# Every degree more than one irreducible character has a zero

Tags: representation-theory

The statement in the title is well known in representation theory, it appears in more than one book as an exercise, but I cannot solve it nor find a proof online, so can someone provide a proof?

For completeness, here is a precise statement.

> Let $G$ be finite group, $\chi$ an irreducible complex character with degree at least 2, show that $\chi$ vanishes on an element of the group.

Comment: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Irreducible_character_of_degree_greater_than_one_takes_value_zero_on_some_conjugacy_class has the result but in the 5th step I don’t see how the inequality is equivalent to Cauchy.

Comment: This is proved in Isaacs' character theory book. See Theorem 3.15.